# How to pass multiple instances of the same option to a kernel module via `/etc/module.d/<module>` config file?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, usb-drive, openwrt

I'm configuring an external USB-to-SATA adapter in OpenWRT (Linux 4.14.221). The hub works only if I bind the device to the `usb-storage` module (preventing it to bind to `usb-storage-uas`).

To do that I added the following line to `/etc/modules.d/usb-storage`

```
usb-storage quirks=<VID>:<PID>:u
```

Where `<VID>` and `<PID>` are my device ids.

In order to do that I had to replace an existing option, which begs the question: what if I had two or more devices that required this setting? How can I pass multiple `quirks`?

I tried with:

```
usb-storage quirks=<VID1>:<PID1>:u
usb-storage quirks=<VID2>:<PID2>:u
```

and

```
usb-storage quirks=<VID1>:<PID1>:u quirks=<VID2>:<PID2>:u
```

But only one is loaded (tested with `cat /sys/module/usb_storage/parameters/quirks`).

OpenWRT doesn't include man pages. The `modprobe.d(5)` manpage on my linux (which I guess is similar, presents a different syntax (`option <modulename> <options...>`) but doesn't mention multiple options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old question, but for anyone ending up here via Google, the correct syntax for multiple quirks is:

```
options usb-storage quirks=<VID1>:<PID1>:u,<VID2>:<PID2>:u,<VID3>:<PID3>:u
```

So basically just put a comma between each quirk.